# apt/ dpkg equivalent to pacman -r

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg, pacman

In arch based system pacman -r/ --root can be used to provide an alternate root to install packages. This sometimes can be a solution to installing package at different location/ partition, dependency conflict etc.

So I'm wondering if there exists any similar solution for debian based systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both tools have an equivalent (based on your description): `dpkg`’s `--root` option, and `apt`’s `RootDir` setting. Both of these change the root directory (temporarily) for everything used by the tools, including configuration, state, package information etc.; they’re intended more for manipulating a mounted system in its entirety, than for installing an individual package in a different location. See [the `dpkg`](https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg) and [`apt.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt.conf) manpages for details.

To change `RootDir`, use `apt`’s `-o` option:

```
apt -o RootDir=/foo ...
```